# State changed from starting to crashed

Tags: heroku, discord.js

So I deployed my Discord bot and it seems fine until at any minute it just crashed. All my files has no errors at all. So here's my log in Heroku.

```
2020-04-17T13:20:43.077260+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-17T13:20:46.867420+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-17T13:20:46.867435+00:00 app[web.1]: > edinburgh@1.0.0 start /app
2020-04-17T13:20:46.867435+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2020-04-17T13:20:46.867436+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-17T13:20:47.375288+00:00 app[web.1]: Edinburgh is ready to go.
2020-04-17T13:21:45.447426+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Can anyone help me? I have no way now to solve this by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your application crashed.. a bit more details would be nice.

- I assume it runs flawlessly when you just execute `node index.js` on your machine
- Back when I used Heroku, it was always a pain in the ass to configure everything around dependency installing, this could be a reason why it crashed, however a JS error would make things much easier
- Also, could you perhaps show your Procfile? I guess it doesn't include a lot but seeing it would be nice